# CSS not found when keep in subfolder

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, master-pages

Here are the two scenarios. Everything is fine in scenario 1. But, problem remain in scenario 2. Please check the scenario:

```
Scenario 1: 
MasterPages: Main\MasterPages.master
Css        : Main\Theme\CSS\
Javascript : Main\Theme\Javascript\

JQuery Menu is loaded successfully

Scenario 2:
MasterPages: Main\MasterPages.master
Css        : Main\Theme\CSS\
Javascript : Main\Theme\Javascript\
Pages      : Main\Pages\Test.aspx(MasterPage is MasterPages.master)

JQuery menu is not loading in Test.aspx page

Please help....
```

Comment: Can you add the code that how are you referencing the stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

It depends where in the code your CSS/JS file is being linked, and therefore what path to specify.

If the links are in `test.aspx` then you would use the followings:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Theme/CSS/filename.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Theme/Javascript/filename.js"></script>
```

However, if the links are in the master page, they would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Theme/CSS/filename.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Theme/Javascript/filename.js"></script>
```

This is because the master page is in the same directory as the `Theme` folder, thus does not need to navigate up the hierarchy using `../`.

Alternatively since you are using ASP.NET you can reference the path absolutely:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Main/Theme/CSS/filename.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Main/Theme/Javascript/filename.js"></script>
```

This assumes that everything is contained in a folder called `Main` that is located at the root of the site.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like you are linking to it correctly. The next thing to do would be to run the site in Chrome, then inspect the source to see what's going on: you can find out whether external files (like JS scripts and CSS files) are actually being served and loaded into the browser and so on. I believe Firefox does the same, but I don't use it so can't comment. Otherwise, host your site somewhere we can see it and I'll take a look and report back.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable reply. the link is in the master page. when the master page loaded, menu loaded successfully. but when i go through pages in masterpages menu, the page is loaded but the menu is not loaded.

Comment: Could you edit your answer, and add in the CSS link text/Javascript text you are using in the master page, as well as the file names of the CSS/javascript files you are trying to link to? Thanks

Comment: when i added like this href="~/Main/Theme/CSS/filename.css" then the menu is not found even in start page

Comment: may b problem in javascript side

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to figure it out is to view the rendered page in code view ('Ctrl+U' in chrome) and see the java and css file url's. Probably you are mising a '../'.

Comment: thanks for reply. it's not found where the problem is but managed in different way..